# Gradle 4.4 -> 4.10: Dependencies being downloaded are not shown anymore

Tags: gradle

I've been using Gradle 4.4 and when downloading dependencies from Maven central, or any repo, it would print this to `stdout` like such:

```
Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom
```

However, after upgrading to Gradle 4.10, it doesn't show this anymore, it just hangs for a while without output, leaving the developer wondering what's going on.

Is there a command line flag or some other option to bring this output back?

Answer (score 7):

This is a change made in Gradle 4.10 , described in the ticket [#6098](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6098), and also discussed in the pull request [PR #6104](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/6104) (see [Gradle 4.10 Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/release-notes.html))

The log level of download events has been reduced by default, but You can turn it on again by using `--info` option.

Comment: Note that the display message has also been changed: instead of "Download https://.....jar" you will get messages like: "Found locally available resource with matching checksum: https://.....jar

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. by using --info option, I won't get the downloaded dependencies log every time.