# Gradle: How print the dependency artifact urls on console

Tags: gradle

We are moved from maven to gradle, In maven, with the build command, we can clearly see the nexus URLs from where the dependencies are fetched.

With gradle how could I see the dependency URLs while the project is building?
Is there any command line option that does this in gradle.

Comment: you should have artifacts URls when executing Gradle with `--info` option, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363180/6899896

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle 4.4 -> 4.10: Dependencies being downloaded are not shown anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344913/gradle-4-4-4-10-dependencies-being-downloaded-are-not-shown-anymore)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log level details related to dependency downloads are not shown by default with gradle.

To enable these dependency download logs, pass the `--info` option or simply `--i` flag with gradle command and it will print the dependency download URLs on the console.